# google play referrer and localy installed app referrer

Tags: android, adb

hi im trying to sideload an app meaning installing the app not from google play but from my apk.
the app is on google play and is referred correctly when downloaded.
however when im installing it on device there is no way to know that i referred it .
i tried using $> pm install --originating-uri    but it say permissons denied.
what is the solution for referring a locally installed app ?

this is what adb says about pm install:

```
              pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f]

              [--algo <algorithm name> --key <key-in-hex> --iv <IV-in-hex>]

              [--originating-uri <URI>] [--referrer <URI>] PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to use the `pm` command with your application UID; you need to be *root* (0) or *shell* (2000). This may be why you are getting a permission denied error.

I successfully set the installer package name with the following command:

```
pm install -i com.test.installer -r filename.apk
```

Tested to make sure Android accepted the installer name:

```
adb shell su -c "grep com.test.installer /data/system/packages.xml"

<package name="test.app" codePath="/data/app/test.app-1.apk" nativeLibraryPath="/data/app-lib/test.app-2" flags="572998" ft="14a75b0a2f0" it="14a6c2e5459" ut="14a75b0a584" version="1" userId="10215" installer="com.test.installer">
```

Comment: this is not what i need i need the google referrer set to some link but in a local install.

Comment: @Chenshov Then change com.test.installer to whatever you want. I just tried http: //example.com and it worked. I don't see why you would want to do that though.

Comment: I don't know what `--referrer` does, but that also didn't give me any issues if I changed the `-i` flag to `--referrer`.